# $location service not passing URL Parameter to Controller

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to pass an **ID** via URL parameter to a page named "**more.html**". So the URL Parameter will like the following.

```
http://example.com/more.html?id=200
```

I used **$location** service in my controller on the more.html page to get the Parameter ID from the URL. Here is the controller code that I used.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($location, $scope, $http) {
    var sno = $location.search().id;
    alert(sno);
});
```

The result I got from the above code was "**Undefined**".

Comment: Try using http://example.com/more.html#?id=200 (add '#'), but why don't you use $state instead of $location? A much cleaner and structured approach. https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router

Comment: The problem is I am passing id via links. like <a href="more.html?id=200">list1</a>, <a href="more.html?id=201">list2</a>. So, I hope its not possible.

Comment: So... That can be changed for using the `$state`approach, not? Or updating the URL.

Comment: Then tell me how to use $state in this case?

Comment: Use the link : https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router which shows you the basics.

Comment: if you use angular-router you can achieve this by using $routeParams

Comment: I've added the changes needed as an answer so you can accept it as the answer, so this SO question is marked as 'solved'. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you `url structure` as following (adding `#`)

from:

```
http://example.com/more.html?id=200
```

to:

```
http://example.com/more.html#?id=200
```

Adding the `#` `more.html` and before your url parameters will fix the problem.
Maybe for your next project you could make use of `ui-router`, which is a more structured way of using `parameters`.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Answer (score 1):

Like what @daan.desmedt told. I changed the URL structure to the following and passed ID via it.

from:

```
http://example.com/more.html?id=200
```

to:

```
http://example.com/more.html#?id=200
```

I added **#** after more.html. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you are not defining the parameters you inject. It should look like below code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', ['$location' , '$scope' , '$http' , function($location, $scope, $http) {
    var sno = $location.search().id;
    alert(sno);
}]);
```